# angularjs multi level editable tree

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree

I'm building my first angularjs app, and still struggling with the scopes and stuff.

I'm trying to build a multi level tree, where I can edit nodes to become sub-nodes, or get them one level up (from sub node to parent), but I'm kind of stuck.

So far, I managed to set a root node as a sub-node. But set a sub-node as a root node is a whole different story, because I have to access the parent node, which right now I don't know how to do.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCeKl0uBw4BxoJAjupND?p=preview)

Any idea of how I can change a sub-node to a root node? Thanks

Edit:

Imagine this tree:

- Item 1

  - Sub Item 1.1 [button 1]
  - Sub Item 1.2 [button 2]
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

You click the [button 2] and you got this:

- Item 1

  - Sub Item 1.1
- Sub Item 1.2
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I has able to figure it out.

Sure, the code looks ugly as hell, but with my limited knowledge of angularjs, that's what I could do. It is not pretty, but does exactly what I want.

Every item could be set as a sub item, with sub items, and them turn them again into root items.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCeKl0uBw4BxoJAjupND?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**this one is dynamic and drag drop tree.**

**http://www.jqueryrain.com/?KIVkhqxl**

it supports:

1. Inputs
2. Custom Templates
3. Action Mapping
4. Events
5. Async Data
6. Filtering
7. Drag & Drop

Features:

1. Dynamically changing the tree
2. API
3. Styling
4. Tri-State Checkboxes
5. Large Trees & Virtual Scroll
6. Redux / Immutable Data